# Only certain areas of image are clickable - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, href, area

So I have a simple  element with a png image in it, however on my page, only some areas of the image are click-able. I have no idea what the problem is.

```css
#thumbnail {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 350px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="Design.html"><img id="thumbnail" src="Design.png"></a>
```

As you can see there is nothing unusual about the image, I don't know why it is doing this. Also in the areas that you can't click, the cursor of course does not change to the pointer.

Comment: When running your code in a jsfiddle the image works just as expected. Don't you have any divs that wrap your image?

Comment: everything seems fine when i tried it in my brackets

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the z-index of the image being the same as the div it was in.